# How should I handle duplicate MAC assignment in the IEEE OUI/MA-L data file?

Tags: mac-address, ieee

I'm trying to create a database for my project to lookup mac vendors. I added a UNIQUE key on the prefix column. When inserting rows from an officially published [MA-L csv file](https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries), I got the duplicate entry error from DB. Then I looked it up in the csv file and found 3 entries for prefix '080030'.

Is the file wrong or I'm misunderstanding how to use the OUI list? If I want to look up the vendor of a mac with prefix '08:00:30', which one of the three is correct?

[image: oui search results on official website]

Comment: I scanned the whole OUI list including MA-L, MA-M, and MA-S, and found 2 duplicate mac prefix in total. One is the '080030' mentioned above, the other one is '0001c8'.

Comment: I''m not using UNIQUE index for now, added a 'LIMIT 1' in the query SQL as a temporary workaround. Still wondering how could there be duplicate entries in such a "unique required" condition

Comment: This is still the case on the latest oui.csv file downloaded just today. Three records for "080030" and two for "0001C8".

Answer (score 2):

There are currently two duplicate assignments in the MA data files.

```
Registry,Assignment,Organization Name,Organization Address
MA-L,080030,NETWORK RESEARCH CORPORATION,2380 N. ROSE AVENUE OXNARD CA US 93010 
MA-L,080030,ROYAL MELBOURNE INST OF TECH,GPO BOX 2476V MELBOURNE VIC AU 3001 
MA-L,080030,CERN,CH-1211  GENEVE SUISSE/SWITZ CH 023
```

```
Registry,Assignment,Organization Name,Organization Address
MA-L,0001C8,THOMAS CONRAD CORP.,1908-R KRAMER LANE AUSTIN TX US 78758 
MA-L,0001C8,CONRAD CORP.,
```

The IEEE provides the following footnote on page 7 of the linked document.

> The IEEE Registration Authority makes a concerted effort to avoid
> duplicate assignments but **does not guarantee that duplicate assignments
> have not occurred**. Global uniqueness also depends on proper use of
> assignments and absence of faults that might result in duplication.

https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/documents/tutorials/eui.pdf

The Wireshark OUI lookup tool, based on their own compiled list, gives one answer for which of these organizations is currently assigned.

```
Network Research Corporation
```

https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup

And the maclookup website, which seems reasonable, gives a different answer.

```
CERN
```

https://maclookup.app/macaddress/080030

There are no timestamps in the data file. There is no explicit row sorting and ordering (and it doesn't look sorted or ordered). Bottom line, there seems to be no way to use the data file and supporting documents alone to determine which assignment is correct.

Comment: I emailed the public address and they provided this explanation, which, honestly, I don't follow, "These assignments were issued by Xerox before IEEE took responsibility for the registry. They are not duplicates because Xerox issued ranges."

Comment: I would assume it means that Xerox informally issued blocks smaller than a full MA-L in a few cases, and both are correct for some subdivisions of the range. It wasn't until a lot later that the IEEE did a similar thing, which is why a lot of lookup tools don't even bother to search the MA-M and MA-S registries.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, never seen such a thing, are you sure you are pulling the correct file from IEEE.

I've reviewed the 3 companies you mentioned in the file, it has different Prefixes.

- [CERN](https://devtools360.com/en/macaddress/lookup/80D336) Mac prefix is 80D336
- [Network Research Corporation](https://devtools360.com/en/macaddress/lookup/080030) has two prefixes, one of which the one mentioned in the question.
- Couldn't find this company in any DB.

I think your parser is somehow corrupted especially if you are parsing the text file.

Comment: I don't think it was a parse error, the error existed in the official database too. The image above was captured on the official website. Since it was so long ago, I think maybe they've fixed the issue.